# ls -g: 'man ls' says -g option has no effect, but it works

Tags: zsh, ls, macos

macOS 14.3, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0). `man ls`:

> `-g`: This option has no effect.  It is only available for compatibility with 4.3BSD, where it was used to display the group name in the long (`-l`) format output.

But it definitily works.

`ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 john  staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 john  staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 john  staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2 john  staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder2
```

`ls -g`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 staff   0 Mar 13 09:06 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2 staff  64 Mar 13 09:06 folder2
```

and `ls -go`:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1    0 Mar 13 09:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1    0 Mar 13 09:06 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2   64 Mar 13 09:06 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2   64 Mar 13 09:06 folder2
```

How this is possible? And is it future-proof to use `ls -g` in scripts?

Comment: The behaviour seen is the one for POSIX `ls -g`, and the manpage seems to be describing the legacy `ls -g` option (compare `COMMAND_MODE=legacy /bin/ls -g` vs `COMMAND_MODE=unix2003 /bin/ls -g`). The mapage date on my 14.4 system is Aug 31, 2020, perhaps this change in behaviour is quite recent?